# Java try-catch block in a method

Tags: java, jdbc, methods, try-catch

I am writing code which uses JDBC to connect to MySQL database. I found myself using this try-catch block for connecting to database multiple times. I use it in several different methods.

```
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);                                   
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);                                                                    
) {
    //here I use different code each time
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there any way to make this try-catch block a method in which I will just write code for the block after try?

Comment: What did you try so far? What's blocking you? Hint: you can use a `Function` parameter for instance.

Comment: I am quite new to programming. I tried to make it a method but I simply couldn't make it. What I mean is that I can send an object to the method but not the whole code for the block.

Comment: You can't move the `catch` to another location, as you might be able to do if Java would have a makro preprocessor like C/C++.
You can delegate the handling of the exception to the caller by declaring the exception on the method (like `public void doDatabase(…) throws SQLException`), but this is different from your question, although you might achieve the same goal with that approach.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want a method that provides a frame consisting of a try-catch and you want to do different things inside it.

And further I assume, that you want to do something with the ResultSet.
As [Gaël](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%c3%abl-j) pointed out, accepting a `Function` would be handy. I made the method accept a generic of T, which the Function returns.

```java
public static <T> Optional<T> execute(final Function<ResultSet, T> mapper, final String query, final String dbURL, final String dbUser, final String dbPassword)
{
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword))
    {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(rs));
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

And you could call it by passing a lambda

```java
Function<ResultSet, MyEntity> mapper = (rs) -> new MyEntity(rs.getString(0));
Optional<MyEntity> result = execute(mapper, query, dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword);
```

Swallowing the exception is not optimal.

I would also consider currying the Function with the query.

Comment: I would consider returning `Optional` rather than null. And yes, handle the exception somehow (left to the reader).

Comment: @GaëlJ, good idea. I updated it.

Comment: You could throw the exception by using a custom functional interface with `throws SQLException` (or even `throws Exception`) on its method, or by using a another parameter with a `Consumer<SQLException>` or something like that to handle the exception.